# apex:page wizard attribute

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have build a Wizard using an apex controller and some VF pages, the thing is that I'm trying to use the wizard property from the apex:page element to be dynamic, instead of using a wizard="true" value I want to determine the rendering from a Boolean declared in my controller like this wizard="{!showWizard}" but no matters what's the value of my var it always shows as if it were false:

```
public CloudCaller_BillingTabController(){
    showWizard = getIsNewInstall();
}

public Boolean showWizard {get;set;}
```

showWizard always have a true value when I check the viewState variables of the controller. I even tried with a jquery ready function to rerender the page and see if changes something but it was unsuccesfull, any thoughts?